# Show a message when entering text in the textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a requirement that is when user entering  text in the textbox i want to show a message (not alert box, this is asp: lable) i.e if user enter "x" in the textbox then i want show a message not after completion of text and not like ontextchanged event. If user cleans textbox then i don't want to show message.

Comment: Are you saying you want to use the `keypress` event? I.e., on each keystroke check the current value of the field and decide what (if any) message to display within another element?

Comment: can u be more clear? what kind of message?

Comment: I want to show <asp:lable> message<asp:lable> i can use onkeypress event but if user clears text box message not hidding and if user press space and escape buttons also showing message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this:

Your textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onKeyUp="my_function(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

where your function `my_function()` is defined as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function my_function(el) {
        var val = this.value;
        if(val && val!="") {
            // Hide your message
            // ....

        } else {
            // Show your message
            // ....

        }
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for replay but i don't want to prevent backspace. I just want to hide message when textbox is cleaned.

Comment: oh I see, do you mean that you don't want to display your message when your textbox is empty? Only for this case right?

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of following three javascript events what ever suits you best,
onkeydown
onkeypress
onkeyup
to understand difference between these events refer to this link

http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/KeyPress-KeyDown-KeyUp-The-Difference-Between-Javascript-Key-Events.aspx